# how to find a maximum of two columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database with a column for the maker, a column for laptop.speed and another one for pc.speed. My question is how I can find which maker has the fastest computer.

```
SELECT distinct product.maker
        FROM product
        LEFT JOIN PC ON PC.model=product.model
        LEFT JOIN laptop ON laptop.model=product.model
        WHERE laptop.speed=(SELECT MAX(laptop.speed) FROM laptop) OR
              PC.speed=(SELECT MAX(PC.speed) FROM PC)
```

This code gives me the maker of the fastest pc and the maker of the fastest laptop.

Comment: Why is this tagged with R?

Comment: because i use R to write my code

Comment: So what R package are we using, `sqldf`?

Comment: i m using sqlite, sorry for not mensioning that

Comment: This package? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html Sorry, just trying to understand if we need an R tag :)

Comment: maybe it's not necessary. but i thought because i use R i'll put the tag. but i will take it away

Comment: Some brands have fast laptops some fast PCs, how do you decide which one to pick?

Comment: A little unclear on the actual table structure. Can you post the relevant bit of definition? These are in separate tables called product, pc, and laptop, yes? Try something like `max( case laptop.speed > pc.speed
            then laptop.speed
            else pc.speed
            end ) speed `. You might need a `HAVING` [clause](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp). I don't have a mysql instance to play with anymore, so I can't test it and give you a more definitive answer.

Comment: yes i have 3 different tables. the product tells me what kind of models each maker has, en in the pc table i can find de models and their speed same thing for the laptop table. that is why i used the join function so that they all come together.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH _speeds AS
  (SELECT pc.model AS model,
          pc.speed AS speed
   FROM pc pc
   ORDER BY pc.speed DESC
   LIMIT 1
   UNION SELECT l.model AS model,
                l.speed AS speed
   FROM laptop l
   ORDER BY pc.speed DESC
   LIMIT 1)
SELECT p.maker
FROM product p
JOIN _speeds s ON s.model = p.model
ORDER BY s.speed DESC
LIMIT 1
```